# Picasso in RecycleView not loading the image

Tags: android, picasso, recyclerview-layout

Supp peeps,
I am creating an ImageLiveFeed app where images will be loading from database to livedata. Picasso in my Adapter is not loading images, I tried manually by putting images in drawable folder and using setImageResource and it works. Here is my Adapter code. Please be nice as I am still learning Android Development

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageHolder> {
        private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
        public static Bitmap bitImg;
        public static Context context;
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ImageHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view =LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.image_item,viewGroup,false);
            this.context=view.getContext();
            return new ImageHolder(view);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageHolder imageHolder, int i) {
                Image currentView = images.get(i);
                Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageHolder.image);
                /*Glide.with(this.context)
                        .load("http://xtraction.live/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/AK-47-Redline.jpg")
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(imageHolder.image);*/
                imageHolder.description.setText(currentView.getDescription());
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return images.size();
        }
        public void setImages (List<Image> images){
            this.images=images;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        class ImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            private TextView description;
            private ImageView image;

            public ImageHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_id);
                image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the `images` ArrayList? It doesn't seem to be doing anything, which makes me think it's probably empty.

Comment: oh thats for my livedata to be passed on to arraylist. I am using a url link to test right now as I have urls saved up in database.

Answer (score 0):

try to this code, may be image size not proper that image not load,

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
.resize(50, 50)
.centerCrop()
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageHolder.image);
```

Comment: not working :(. I tried debugging too and no issue there. Thanks doe